# 1-sided two sample t-test with covariate adjustment

Tags: t-test

I have a biological problem which involves using a 1-sided two-sample t-test. To simplify the problem, let’s assume an experiment comparing quantities in a control (C) and a treatment (T) group, each having 3 replicates, called C1, C2, C3, T1, T2, T3. Here, **C1 and T1 are samples from the same subject, C2 and T2 are samples from the same subject, and so on.**

Now I obtain a number for each of the following combinations. "within" = within group (i.e. both are C or both are T). Also, the number after C or T indicate whether they're from the same subject (sub) or not.

```
C1_C2 (within: different sub)
C1_C3 (within: different sub)
C1_T1 (between: same sub)
C1_T2 (between: different sub)
C1_T3 (between: different sub)
C2_C3 (within: different sub)
C2_T1 (between: different sub)
C2_T2 (between: same sub)
C2_T3 (between: different sub)
… (a total of 15 pairwise quantities)
```

We are essentially interested in comparing the quantities "within" group and the quantities "between" group, but **hoping to incorporating the "subject" effect somehow in the t-test**. Is there a way to distinguish “different sub” and “same sub” in the test?

Thank you so much for your suggestions!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and use linear regression using [dummy variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_%28statistics%29). Try to regress the difference of each pair (let's call it $Y_i$) with a dummy variable marking if it's a "between" group ($D_1$ which can get 1 if it's "between" or 0 if it's "within") and an interaction dummy variable $D_1\cdot D_2$ ($D_2$ gets 1 if it's "same sub" of 0 otherwise). 
So the regression equation will be:
$Y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1\cdot D_{1,i} + \beta_2\cdot D_{1,i}\cdot D_{2,i} + \epsilon_i$
where:
$Y_i$ - each pairwise difference
$D_{1,i}$ - 1 if it's "between", 0 otherwise
$D_{2,i}$ - 1 if it's "same sub", 0 otherwise

The results can be interpreted:
$\beta_0$ - the mean difference in the "within" group
$\beta_0 + \beta_1$ - the mean difference in the "between" group, without "same sub" 
$\beta_0 + \beta_1+ \beta_2$ - the mean difference in the "between" group, with "same sub"
If you run this regression in [stata](http://www3.nd.edu/~rwilliam/stats2/l51.pdf), for example, you will get the t-test result for each $\beta$, so you could know if it's statistically significant. If $\beta_1$ is significant, it means that the change between the groups is significant. If $\beta_2$ is significant, it means that the "same sub"/"different sub" distinction is significant.
[Dummy variables - additional explanation](http://www.sagepub.com/upm-data/21120_Chapter_7.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Since the "same sub" samples are only in the "between" group, we need to know if they affect its mean. I would suggest running another test to compare the mean difference in the "between" group **with** the "same sub" samples and the mean difference in this group **without** the "same sub" samples (without C1_T1, C2_T2, C3_T3).
If this test will show no significant difference, then those samples do not affect the mean of the group, and you can run the test between the 2 groups. 
If the test will show a significant difference, then you practically have 3 groups (within, between different subs, between same sub), and you can continue and assign a biological meaning to it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Yes, I can make such comparisons to see if the "same sub" will affects the mean of the "between" group. However, I am just curious if there is a way to automatically account for such "extra" grouping, i.e. assuming there is an underlying significant difference present... Thanks ;-)

Comment: @Iyosef769: thank you so much! Sorry I mean to award the bounty for  your answer above ;-)